# Will my app be rejected if I use CallKit framework to check status of ongoing call even if my app does not have any VOIP functionality?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, callkit

I am working on an app that has one section from where user can tap on a mobile number to make cellular calls. To make call, I am using following code.

```
if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel://\(9999999999)") {

        let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL)
            }
        }
    }
```

This shows an alert with option to Call or Cancel. Now when I select Call option, I need to check the state of the ongoing call.
To do this I am making use of CallKit framework.

```
var callObserver = CXCallObserver()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
}

func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {

    if call.hasConnected {

    }

    if call.isOutgoing {

    }

    if call.hasEnded {

    }

    if call.isOnHold {

    }
}
```

This delegate methods receives callback when an outgoing call starts or ends.

Now since my app does not have any functionality related to VOIP, I just want to know if it is OK to use CallKit framework like this to know the call status.

Will my app be rejected for Appstore upload if I use CallKit like this and not have a VOIP functionality in the app?
Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Can you update if your app was approved or you had to make amendments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, CallKit.framework's `CXCallObserver` API may be used by any app, regardless of whether that app provides VoIP calling functionality itself or not.

Note however that it's not guaranteed that any particular call that your app observes are the result of the user deciding to call based on your app's opening of a `tel:` URL. It is possible that the user declined to open the `tel:` URL that your app offered to open, and instead dialed a call separately or received an incoming call around the same time period, and your app would receive similar-looking `CXCallObserver` delegate callbacks regardless. It's not possible to reliably distinguish between calls initiated outside your app from those started from your app.

Comment: Thanks Stuart for clearing my doubt regarding app store upload. Yes I also agree that a call made from dialer can also trigger these delegate callbacks.  Cheers...

Comment: @AMUL Can you please let us know how you went with the submission?